# Get post only from 'standard' post format

Tags: posts, post-formats

I use the following codes to get posts **only** from '**image**' post format and it works.

```
<?php if( has_post_format('image')){ ?>
   <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I also need to get posts **only** from '**standard**' post format with the following codes, but it get post from all post formats.

```
 <?php if( has_post_format('standard')){ ?>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do,

```
<?php if( false == get_post_format() ){ ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

The standard post format isn't actually a post format, so if you conditionally check whether a post contains a post format (other than the default standard), it will return `false`, because it's set to... *standard*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also found a way myself: if( !get_post_format() ). this code also works nice.

Comment: No problem. `!get_post_format()` is essentially doing the same thing, `!` aka `NOT`, but technically the above would be better written as `get_post_format() === false`, which will only return `true` when `get_post_format()` returns false, which it does when checking for the standard post type. Now, `false ==` will also return `true` for an empty string `''`, `null` and `0`, so if they are not the expected, anticipated or potential values of output then it's best to go with `===` IMO. But glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Exclude all rest terms using 'NOT IN' operator.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'   => 'desc',
    'posts_per_page'    => '4',
    'tax_query'             => array( array(
        'taxonomy'          => 'post_format',
        'field'             => 'slug',
        'terms'             => array('post-format-aside', 'post-format-gallery', 'post-format-link', 'post-format-image', 'post-format-quote', 'post-format-status', 'post-format-audio', 'post-format-chat', 'post-format-video'),
        'operator'          => 'NOT IN'
    ) ),                   
);
```

Comment: Welcome to wpse! Your question is incomplete, you only created a variable that I assume you will use as a argument for `get_posts()` OR `WP_query`, going by OPs question, could you create a complete example on how to achieve that?